# replace select option:selected with div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to take all the `<select>` elements within a particular `<div>` and capture the option selected, then replace the select box with a `<div>` containing the selected option. Here is the code I have so far, but it isn't working. it copies all the selected options from all the select boxes on the page into each div instead of just the one selected in the select tag it's replacing.

```
$('#receivecontainer select').each(function() {  
    $('select option:selected').replaceWith(function() {
        return $('<div>' + $('option:selected').text() + '</div>');
    });
});
```

Comment: You can't replace an `<option>` with a `<div>`. `<select>` elements cannot have anything but `<option>`s and `<optgroup>`s as children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to grab the option selected and add it to a div placed after that select element. Then go back and remove the element before proceeding to the next select.

```
$('#receivecontainer select').each(function() { 
            var selectvalue = $("option:selected", this).text();
            $('<div class="answer">' +selectvalue+ '</div>').insertAfter(this);
            $(this).remove();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select").change(function(){
    var text = $("select option:selected")
        .not(":contains('Select one')")
        .text();
    $("<div>")
        .html( text )
        .appendTo("#container");
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/dvPau/).

We're firing this function when the `select` is changed (a new option is selected).

The function takes the selected option's text and appends it to the container as a new `div`.

It also ignores the `Select one` option if it is selected.

Comment: $('#receivecontainer select') does not select a single element by an id. It selects all selects in a single element selected by an id, so each() is ok.

Comment: @MilošRašić: Yes, I realized that a few minutes after I posted, lol. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

It's doing exactly what you told it to do. Your final $('option:selected') simply selects all the selected options on the page. Also, there is no need to iterate through all the selects because you can simply select the options and iterate through them. Finally, there is no need to turn the selected option into text just to add it to html string which will be converted back into an element. Here's how I would solve your problem:

```
//select all selected options and iterate through them
//there is no need to select the selects because there should be no options outside a select
$('#receivecontainer option:selected').each(function() {
    var newDiv = $('<div></div>').html($(this).text()); //create an empty div and fill it with the contents of the option
    $(this).replaceWith(newDiv); //replace the option with the created div
});
```

Just out of curiosity, does putting a div in a select work ok and consistent across the browsers? I wouldn't expect it to.

Comment: Excellent  however, I'm trying to replace the select with the div not place the div inside it

Comment: Then $(this).parent().replaceWith(newDiv);